# Get array value using key, in XDebug for PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xdebug

Having an array $a and a key $key, it's usually as simple as $a[$key] to get the value for that key in the array.
However, if the array is returned by a function like this:

```
function getArray(){
    return array('a' => someObjectValue1, 'b' => someObjectValue2);
}
echo getArray()['a'];
```

, then you can't simply do getArray()[$key] as in some versions of PHP this would give you

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Then ofcourse something like this would work:

```
$a = getArray();
echo $a['a'];
```

but I'm in the Watch window of XDebug and I can't do that.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do it that way?

Comment: The second way is the correct one.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The first example you give works since PHP 5.4.0, the second example will work in every version.

Comment: @betadevil problem is that in debugger you can only evaluate _expressions_ but not execute any code. So OP wants to get value as an expression, i.e. one-liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to resolve that. For example, one-liner for display desired value may be:

```
function foo()
{
   return array('bar'=>1, 'baz'=>2);
}

$value = array_shift(array_intersect_key(foo(), array('baz'=>null))); //you want $value
```

-but this looks weird and may be it have sense to create debug function, like:

```
function getValueByKey(array $array, $key)
{
   return $array[$key];
}

$value = getValueByKey(foo(), 'baz');
```